# Regular Expression matching in Python to extract all hashtags and its adjacent punctuations?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to extract all the hashtags adjacent to other hashtags/punctuations so that I can get the bigrams from them. For the following variable `c` I want to extract the output of `['! #helloworld #goodday #winter #christmastime !']`

```
c = 'Hello!! This is a good day! #helloworld #goodday #winter #christmastime!'
re.findall(r'(?:#[a-zA-Z]+ #[a-zA-Z]+)|(?:[\!"#\$%&\'\(\)*+,-./\:;<=>\?\@\[\\]\^_`{|}~]+ #[a-zA-Z]+)',b)
```

**Actual Output:** 
['#helloworld #goodday', '#winter #christmastime']

**Expected Output:**
['! #helloworld #goodday #winter #christmastime !']

Which regular expression should be used for extracting the expected output from the string?

Comment: Try [`re.findall(r'[^\w\s](?:\s*#[a-zA-Z]+)+(?:\s*[^\w\s])?',c)`](http://rextester.com/CUG41920) (if the whitespace is always there, use `\s+` instead of `\s*`)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I need the punctuations even if it is after the hashtag and can you provide an explanation please. I read about greedy search using `?:` but I could not get it to work so details about how this regex works will be really helpful

Comment: See my edited comment, see http://rextester.com/CUG41920, too. Does it work as expected?

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew. Can you add it as an answer with details about `?:` and why your regex works, please?

Comment: [`(?:...)` is a non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
[^\w\s](?:\s*#[a-zA-Z]+)+(?:\s*[^\w\s])?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JALNnm/1). If there are always at least 1 whitespace, replace `\s*` with `\s+`.

**Details**

- `[^\w\s]` - a punctuation symbol (any 1 char other than word and whitespace char)
- `(?:\s*#[a-zA-Z]+)+`  - a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon) matching 1 or more sequences of:

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `#` - a `#` symbol
  - `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1+ ASCII letters
- `(?:\s*[^\w\s])?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `[^\w\s]` - a punctuation symbol (any 1 char other than word and whitespace char)

[Python demo](http://rextester.com/CUG41920):

```
import re
c = 'Hello!! This is a good day! #helloworld #goodday #winter #christmastime!'
print(re.findall(r'[^\w\s](?:\s*#[a-zA-Z]+)+(?:\s*[^\w\s])?',c))
# => ['! #helloworld #goodday #winter #christmastime!']
```